# Are some badge awards delayed?

Tags: discussion, badges

I answered a [question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/47900/what-movie-features-a-hovering-spherical-robot-that-kills-a-man-with-a-propeller/47901#47901) that has so far received an acceptance and 11 points. For this I got the Nice Answer badge, but did not get an Enlightened (first to answer and accepted with a score of ten or more) badge. This has not happened to me before. Is there sometimes a lag between meeting criteria and receiving the badge? I thought it was automated. Is there some other reason it was not awarded?

Comment: With those two in particular, I don't seem to get awarded "Enlightened" until immediately after I've viewed the alert for "Nice Answer".  Though it _may_ have been a bug in the old userbar, since I dont't think I've gotten them simultaneously since the new one was released.

Comment: It was 4 months before I got my Mortarboard. The delay can be significant.

Comment: That must be the most-asked question on meta. I remember asking it myself, back when I was new here :-)

Comment: I searched "badge" "delayed", but turned up nothing. I assumed it would have been asked, just didn't find it. I had a mortarboard take a while, too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Badges are calculated at regular intervals, not all the time.

Processing badges--especially badges with multiple criteria--takes resources, so the site is automated to check for new badge qualifications at certain intervals rather than running that check constantly.

The next time the site checks for badge qualifications, you'll get yours. It usually takes much less than 24 hours for the jobs to run, but the more complicated the badge qualifications the longer the delay between checks. If you haven't got the badge after 24 hours, then you can be concerned.

Comment: Sorry, thought [the badger script](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/181456) had been fixed to keep that from happening. (Although it was very tempting to write about badger koalafications.)

Comment: Yeaaa! The Enlightened Badger just clawed its way through the internet to get to my screen!

Comment: No, not fixed yet. Sorry. :(

Comment: @BESW -100 for "koalafications"